# Mathematical function to increase perceived linearity of a volume slider

Tags: javascript, function

**Background**

I'm not a mathematician, but I know precisely what I need. Please bear with my non-mathematical explanation.

**Synopsis**

I'd like help with a javascript function that will map an input slider to an output number, with the following two requirements. I'm controlling a digital mixer, but with a simple x - 100 = y relationship, it's really insensitive at the bottom end of the slider, and really sensitive at the top. Later I will control other devices like lighting dimmers, so I'd like to understand as much as I can about such functions, without getting unnecessarily deep into the maths.

- The input values are always 0 to 100, and output values in the range -99 to a specified number between x and y, for example 0, or 5. (i.e. This number to be easily changed in the function.)
- Needs to be non-linear, like the curve shown below (output changes more quickly at bottom end of slider), however it needs to be a steeper curve. I cannot work out with maths how to do that. I tried both mathematical functions ln() and log() on a graphical calculator but couldn't get near what I need. In fact I'd like to understand what I'd need to do to specify or tweak the curve in the following two ways: steepness of curve, and a way to mirror the curve so that changes would be GREATER at the beginning as opposed to what I've described above.

[image]

Comment: hi, you should show us what you've tried so far. We're not here to do your work. You should have known this, as a Member for over 7 years...

Comment: "I'd like help with a javascript function" Where is your function?  Please add it to your question.

Comment: Your requirements are too vague - you don't know "precisely" what you need. There infinitely many curves that would suit what you have specified. What is this for? You need to provide a lot more information. No one here is going to trial and error their way to an answer for you.

Comment: @J.Sadi "what I've tried so far" is in the image on this page. I have specified a mathematical function which doesn't give me exactly what I need. Square root of 150x minus 100 equals y. I will update the original post with the Javascript I used.

Comment: @J.Stott No, my requirements are for a function that allows me to specify the degree of the curve, and the y crossing point for x=100. Those are two well-defined requirements. How can I be more specific?

Comment: I do wish SO users would not immediately punish this post. It may not seem it, but I spent the best part of 45 minutes honing the wording of my post, and downvoting like that means the post doesn't get seen by others, thus wasting the time I put into it. I certainly don't expect others to "do my work for me". I have been quite clear with the help I need, and will update the post where clarification is required.

Comment: The problem here is that the help you need is starting from scratch (no code) which will always get you downvoted here.  I'm sure that if you update (or maybe delete-and-repost) this question with your attempts at solving your own problem, folks will be happy to help you out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are endless possibilities, so this is going to be a guess. Using the same kind of formula that you tried with, i.e. with a square root of *x*, there are three parameters that can be identified:

- The Y value where the curve should cross the Y-axis
- The X value where the curve should cross the X-axis
- The magnitude of the curvature (bending)

The last parameter can be influenced by changing the power which you apply to *x*. So if you would use 1/3 instead of 1/2, then the bending will be stronger.

It is quite simple to see how the first two parameters influence the function.

Here is a function that returns the actual function based on those three parameters:

```
function createFunc(y0, x0, power) {
    const inv = 10 / power;
    const c = y0 / (x0 ** inv);
    return function f(x) {
        return c * (x ** inv) - y0;
    }
}
```

The number 10 in this logic allows the `power` to be an integer and yet be sensitive enough. So for a square root you would pass the value 20: then `inv` becomes 1/2.

Here is a little demo allowing you to interactively change these three parameters and see the resulting plot:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const shiftX = 10.5;
const shiftY = 10.5;
ctx.translate(shiftX, shiftY);
const rangeX = [-shiftX, canvas.width-shiftX];
const rangeY = [-shiftY, canvas.height-shiftY];

function display(f) {
    ctx.clearRect(rangeX[0], rangeY[0], rangeX[1], rangeY[1]);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    ctx.moveTo(rangeX[0], 0);
    ctx.lineTo(rangeX[1], 0);

    ctx.moveTo(0, rangeY[0]);
    ctx.lineTo(0, rangeY[1]);
    
    for (let i = 10; i < canvas.width; i+= 10) {
        ctx.moveTo(i, -2); ctx.lineTo(i, +2);
    }
    for (let i = 10; i < canvas.height; i+= 10) {
        ctx.moveTo(-2, i); ctx.lineTo(+2, i);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    if (!f) return;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.moveTo(0, f(0));
    for (let x = 0; x < rangeX[1]; x++) {
        ctx.lineTo(x, f(x));
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
function createFunc(y0, x0, power) {
    const inv = 10 / power;
    const c = y0 / (x0 ** inv);
    return function f(x) {
        return c * (x ** inv) - y0;
    }
}

function update() {
    const f = createFunc(+inputs[0].value, +inputs[1].value, +inputs[2].value);
    display(f);
}

document.oninput = update;
update();
```

```css
canvas { background: #eee; float: left }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas><br>
Play with these numbers!<br>
Cross Y-axis at: <input type="number" min="-130" max="-10" value="-100"><br>
Cross X-axis at: <input type="number" min="10" max="200" value="100"><br>
Bend: <input type="number" min="10" max="200" value="20"><br>
```

The resulting graph sticks quite close to the Y axis. A similar study and graphing could be achieved with a logarithm, where with the third parameter you would change the *base* of the logarithm.

Many other techniques exists, like Bézier curves. See for instance [Curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting).